# Detect and convert URL in String Java, Is regex better or even faster?

Tags: java, regex, string, url

The bellow code detects and converts urls in String. Is there faster way or more elegant way to do this block of code?:

```
public static String detectAndConvertURLs(String text) {
    String[] parts = text.split("\\s");
    String rtn = text;
    for (String item : parts)
        try {
          // adjustment based one of the answers 
          Pattern p = Pattern.compile("((mailto\\:|(news|(ht|f)tp(s?))\\://){1}\\S+)");
          Matcher m = p.matcher(item);
          if( m.matches() ) item = m.group(1);

            URL url = new URL(item);
            String link = url.getProtocol() + "://" + url.getHost() + "/" + (url.getPath() == null ? "" : url.getPath()) + (url.getQuery() == null ? "" : "?" + url.getQuery());
            rtn = StringUtils.replace(rtn, item, "<a rel=\"nofollow\" href=\"" + link + "\">" + link + "</a> ");
        } catch (MalformedURLException ignore) {
        }
    return rtn;
}
```

Comment: Speed and elegance considerations aside, this code will also not detect URLs in brackets, such as `[1][http://www.google.com/]`.

Comment: Where are you take String text? Is it long/short?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I would use regular expressions such as:

```
public static String detectAndConvertURLs(String text) {
   //Regex pattern (unescaped), matches any Internet URL: 
   //((mailto\:|(news|(ht|f)tp(s?))\://){1}\S+)
   Pattern p = Pattern.compile( "((mailto\\:|(news|(ht|f)tp(s?))\\://){1}\\S+)" );
   Matcher m = p.matcher( text );
   if( m.matches() ){
      return m.group(1);
   }else return null;
}
```

I just took that regex from this site of useful regex expressions:

http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=URL

A quick google search will produce many regex expression resources:

http://www.google.com/search?q=regex+match+url&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a

You might have to massage the regex a little to trim stuff at the beginning or end depending on your use.

Comment: Make at least `p` a class variable. It's pretty expensive to compile the same on every method call again and again.

Comment: Never done any performance tests myself, it would be very easy (only a few minutes) to do some tests though. As BalusC said, only compile it once. As for complexity, that's a tough one. Regexes can get ugly. The rule is always to start simple and build in more complexity one piece at a time. You might consider trying multiple Regexes to mitigate that (one to look for IPv4, another for IPv6, and the like), I'm not sure how much of a performance tradeoff it would be, but you could try running a few loops of 10,000 tests to see in just a few minutes time. Let us know if you do those tests too.

Comment: These days CPU is generally a reasonably cheap commodity, so it's often better to the overall project to code for correctness and robustness than to try to save every single cpu cycle. I would generally suggest doing it the way that is easiest to understand, extend, and debug first, profile your application, and only if you see too much CPU taken by these methods, then come back and re-work them for speed.